# error ENOENT,open with gridFS and node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gridfs, gridfs-stream

I am trying to save a project and its file using GridFS. I want to save project first and use "_id" of project as metadata for file.

Here is my code:

```
        newProject.save(function (err,project) {
        if (err) {
        console.log('save error', err);
        }
        console.log("project added");
        var id=poject._id;
        var filepath    = req.files.file.path;
        var filename    = req.files.file.name;
        var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({ filename: filename, metadata:id });
        console.log(filepath);                                                       
        fs.createReadStream(filepath)
        .on('end', function() {

        })
        .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log("error encountered"+err);//ENOENT,open error  
        })
        .pipe(writestream);
        });
```

I am getting following error:-
ENOENT, open '/tmp/45e85388793de'

I know that this error comes when the directory does not exists. As you can see I am writing the file after saving the project since I need to link the file to the project. That's why I have written the code to save the file inside callback function of project.save() but it is not working there. If I put the same code outside the .save block the same code works perfectly for same path. (I have displayed the path both inside and outside and they are same)

Comment: It would be nice if you'd provide the real code...and more of it for context. You have typo in `poject._id`. Is your `/tmp` writeable?

Comment: yes my /tmp is writable. And the same code successfully uploads the file if it is outside the callback function. I gave some more thought to the problem. Do you think this has something to do with file getting removed from the 'tmp' directory when i am inside callback of save function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to fix this myself:-

File is saved in a temporary location. When you are inside the callback function your file is removed from that location and you are getting "No such file" error. Path and other variables still exists as part of js and that's why you are able to print them in console.

Solution: Above(Outside) callback function move your file to some other permanent location using:

```
    fs.rename(req.files.file.path, "./someKnownPath/filename");
```

Keep note of that location. In your callback function use the new location as path and try saving the file in gridfs. Once the file is saved you may delete it file from that location(/someKnownPath/filename).